# Moving a UIImageView from left to center

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to move my image view from left to the center of the view.

Following is my code:

```
CGPoint origin = self.headerImage.center;
CGPoint target = CGPointMake(0, self.headerImage.center.x);

CABasicAnimation *bounce = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
bounce.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:origin.x];
bounce.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:target.x];
[self.headerImage.layer addAnimation:bounce forKey:@"position"];
```

It has to start moving from the left and stop at the center when the view controller is loaded. But it is not working properly. How can I sort this out?

Comment: What is the issue with your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `target` needs to indicate the center of the view: `CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y)`
2. Change `fillMode` `removedOnCompletion` `autoreverses` `repeatCount` to avoid frame changes (final of animation)

Final code:

```
CGPoint origin = self.headerImage.center;
CGPoint target = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y);
CABasicAnimation *bounce = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
bounce.duration = 1;
bounce.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:origin.x];
bounce.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:target.x];
bounce.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
bounce.removedOnCompletion = NO;
bounce.autoreverses = NO;
bounce.repeatCount = 0;
[self.headerImage.layer addAnimation:bounce forKey:@"position"];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
self.headerImage.transform = transform;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    headerImage.frame = myNewFrameRect;
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here :

```
CGPoint origin = self.headerImage.center;
CGPoint target = CGPointMake(0, self.headerImage.center.x);
```

You're not aiming at the correct target, you're aiming at the current center of your `headerImage` ; so technically, `origin` and `target` are the same location here.

Move the target to the center of the superview, and you'll be good :)

```
CGPoint target = CGPointMake(0, self.headerImage.superView.center.x);
```

You could also probably use `self.view.center.x`, but it's slightly less future proof.

Also, I've noticed the keys you're using differ between the two times you use it ("position" and "position.x"). I'm not super comfortable with CAAnimations, so this might be completely right in the first place